# Передача данных из функции в div (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, javascript-events

При нажатии на кнопку не отображается на экране значение переменной `p1`. Код на Typescript.

```
//компонент Main
export function Main() {

  //переменные
  let p1;
  let p2: any = "1";
  let a = 2, b = 2;

  //функция
  function f(){
    if (a == b) {p1 = p2}
  }

  //содержимое (кнопка и отображаемые данные)
  return(
    <div>
      <button className='next' id='next' onClick={f}>Test</button>
      {p1}
    </div>
  );

}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При нажатии на кнопку не отображается на экране значение переменной p1

Так и должно быть. Поскольку не выполняется твое условие

```
if (a == b)
```

Так же еще нужно помнить что рендер компонента вызывается

- изменением стейта
- изменением пропсов

Ни того, ни другого в твоем компоненте нет.

Запускай мой пример, жми на кнопку и смотри в консоль...

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector('#root'))

function Main() {
  const [p1, setP1] = React.useState(null)
  //переменные
  /*let p1;*/
  let p2 = "1";
  let a = 2, b = 2;
  function f(){
    if (a == b) setP1(p2)
  }
  /*
  //функция
  function f(){
    console.log('Смотри входные данные', a, b, a == b)
    if (a == b) {p1 = p2}
    console.log('Смотри p1', p1)
  }
  */

  //содержимое (кнопка и отображаемые данные)
  return(
    <div>
      <button className='next' id='next' onClick={f}>Test</button>
      <p>{p1}</p>
    </div>
  );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Изменил строку ``let a,b = 2``.Теперь ``let a = 2; b = 2``. Но переменная ``p1`` все равно не отображается.

Comment: @ProgHuman, немудрено! Поскольку рендер компонента вызывают - изменение стейта или пропсов. У тебя нет таких изменений, потому компонент не рендерится. Сделай стейт для переменной `p1`, меняй его по "правилам стейта" - компонент будет рендерится (перерисовываться).

Comment: @ProgHuman, смотри последний вариант моего примера. Уже с использованием стейта.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Сделаю поправку, что пишу на Typescript, и выходит ошибка:
Аргумент типа "string | undefined" нельзя назначить параметру типа "SetStateAction<null>".
  Тип "undefined" не может быть назначен для типа "SetStateAction<null>".

Comment: Как ни странно, вывод на экран происходит, если отталкиваться от результата, можно считать, что проблема решена, но ошибка все равно висит

Comment: Решил проблему, изменив строку ``let p2 = "1"`` на ``let p2: any = "1"``. Теперь компилятор не ругается. Проблема решена. Еще раз спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ProgHuman, я с `Typescript` дело не имею... Т.ч. тут я пас.